# Does the drone has 'AutoCorrect' location function?

Tags: android, dji-sdk

The situation is as the following:

1. The drone gets a single mission which is `GoToAction` and moving from point 'Home' to point 'A'.
2. Afterwards the drone is being controlled through virtual stick with `FlightController.sendVirtualStickFlightControlData()` method and moving from point 'A' to 'B'.
3. At point 'B' the drone gets another `GoToAction` mission to go to point 'Home'.

**The problem:**
When the virtual stick stops sending data, the drone is starting the process of breaking (as the speed is higher then the breaking process will take more space to stop the drone) which is ok, and then the drone gets another `GoToAction` mission in which he suppose to go to point 'Home', what actually happens is that the drone first of all going back to the point that he *started the breaking process* and only when he back to point 'B' (the start of the breaking process) he then staring the next `GoToAction`.

Is there a way to cancel this 'AutoCorrect' which he is doing by him self?

Drone - Mavic Pro Platinum

SDK - 4.9

Android - 9

[image]